# how should I model my data for JS app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, model, db-schema

I am using JavaScript (without any framework) to create a client only application, will be using MongoDB to store the data. I can think of **2 ways** to model my data.

Can someone please help me to understand which is more appropriate.

- **Way #1**

  ```
  [{
      title: "bucketList",
      id: 1,
      tasks: [{
          title: "play soccer for world league",
          id: 1,
          done: false,
          comments: ["fifa 2014 is about to start", "need to go buy a Brazil T-shirt"]
      }, {
          title: "start a school",
          id: 2,
          done: true,
          comments: ["start with being a mentor"]
      }]
  }, {
      title: "to-do",
      id: 2,
      tasks: [{
          title: "create a todo App",
          id: 1,
          done: false,
          comments: []
      }, {
          title: "watch GOT",
          id: 2,
          done: false,
          comments: ["whitewalkers seems to be in no hurry"]
      }]
  }]
  ```
- **Way #2**

  ```
  [{
      collection - title: "bucketList",
      collection - id: 1,
      title: "play soccer for world league",
      id: 1,
      done: false,
      comments: ["fifa 2014 is about to start", "need to go buy a Brazil T-shirt"]
  }, {
      collection - title: "bucketList",
      collection - id: 1,
      title: "start a school",
      id: 2,
      done: true,
      comments: ["start with being a mentor"]
  }, {
      collection - title: "to-do",
      collection - id: 2,
      title: "create a todo App",
      id: 1,
      done: false,
      comments: []
  }, {
      collection - title: "to-do",
      collection - id: 2,
      title: "watch GOT",
      id: 2,
      done: false,
      comments: ["whitewalkers seems to be in no hurry"]

  }]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

My two pennies are:

I actually depends how you want to work with your data.

way#1 you manage a whole do do list at once with many do dos
way#2 gives you direct access to each to do.

way#1 makes it easy to access all to-dos from one list but updating "done" for example will be a bit more work since it's an array.

way#2 makes updates of "done" easier but you need some iteration / aggregation to find all do dos of a list.

way#2 seems easier to handle to me since updates on done for example are easier to handle while a find with more than one document is easy to handle.
Also take in consideration what you want to do with your data, for example if you had a due date and you want to display all due tasks across all to-do lists way#2 would be  def. the better choice.